# Why my add friend testing route goes through in insomina with 200 OK, but it's not nested when I call to get all users?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, mongoose, routes

I am working with mondoDB and moongose NoSQL. When I try to add a friend to a user, I have this code.

```
 addFriend({ params }, res) {
   User.updateOne
   ({ _id: params.friendId })
     .then(dbUserData => res.json(dbUserData))
     .catch(err => res.json(err));
 },
```

http://localhost:3001/api/users/61286c3285a0afa77a1b869e/friends/6128178de88611885576fdd6

That's the testing route and I get this:

```
{
  "driver": true,
  "name": "MongoError",
  "index": 0,
  "code": 66
}
```

The goal is to have it added in the main route:

http://localhost:3001/api/users

This is what I get:

```
 {
    "_id": "61286c3285a0afa77a1b869e",
    "username": "testing",
    "email": "testing@gmail.com",
    "friends": []
  },
```

The goal is to have it nested into the friend's array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for updating doc you must query to specific doc `userId` and update the doc `push` friendId to friend field

```
addFriend({ params }, res) {
   User.updateOne
   ({ _id: params.userId },{$push:{friends:params.friendId})
     .then(dbUserData => res.json(dbUserData))
     .catch(err => res.json(err));
 },
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time on reading my code. I got something different now. It's nested in the main route, but says null. I am expecting to have nested the user's id into a different friend's array.